# Write a crochet pattern generator

Tags: code-golf

## Introduction

I crochet a lot, and lately I've started writing crochet patterns. However, while I work very well from notes such as *rnds 2-6 (round number = x, original number of stitches = y): *dc x-2 stitches, 2 dc in next stitch* around (xy stitches)*, most published patterns spell out each row in more detail. I don't like writing out each individual row/round myself though, so I want to have a program do it for me.

## Challenge

The challenge is to write a program or function that takes three mandatory inputs (r, s, and y) and returns a string of the pattern.

### Inputs

The inputs can go in any appropriate order or format, just please point that out so others can run your code.

R is an integer corresponding to the number of rounds/rows (use whichever designation you want) to generate. S is a string corresponding to the type of stitch. This can be guaranteed to be one of the following strings: "tc", "dc", "hdc", "sc", or "ch". Y is the number of stitches in row/round 1, and the number of increases in each following row (for instance, if y=6, row 1 has 6 stitches, row 2 has 12 stitches, row 3 has 18 stitches, etc). In the general case: row x has xy stitches.

### Outputs

The output is a list of strings with length r, in the following pattern.

`O N: \*s in next N-2 stitches, 2 s in next stitch\* y times (NY stitches).`

To clarify: it should return r strings, in order from least row/rnd number to greatest row/rnd number. The first row/rnd should be row 1, and the last row should be row r. In the template, replace s and y with the matching inputs, and N is the row number of the current row (N isn’t an input, just an integer that represents the current row). O is used to denote one of the following strings, your choice: “Row”, “Round”, or “Rnd”.

Each line of output should be separated by a newline. The period is necessary and should follow the parentheses.

### Edge Cases

You can assume s is one of the listed strings. R will always be a positive integer, as will y.

You don’t have to do anything fancy for row 1, it can be `Row 1: \*s in next -1 stitches, 2 s in next stitch\* y times (y stitches).` Row 2 can also be outputted in the default format, as `Row 2: \*s in next 0 stitches, 2 s in next stitch\* y times (2y stitches).` Thusly, it can be outputted with a for loop. But, if you output rows 1 and 2 as `Row 1: s in next y stitches (y stitches).\nRow 2: 2 s in next y stitches (2y stitches).`, you can have -10% or -10 bytes, whichever is smaller, removed from your score.

### Scoring

This is code golf, so fewest bytes wins. If you output rows 1 and 2 as shown in the Output section above, your score is lowered by -10% or -10 bytes, whichever is smaller.

## Example Input and Output

Input [the format doesn’t matter so much as the answer, so it could be any format the language supports]: (r,s,y)

> 1. (5, “dc”, 6)
> 2. (3, “sc”, 1)
> 3. (6, “hdc”, 100)
> 4. (0, “ch”, 1)
> 5. (5, “tc”, 0)

Output [this format must be fairly exact, hyphens are used to show negative numbers]:

> 1. `Row 1: \*dc in next -1 stitches, 2 dc in next stitch\* 6 times (6 stitches).\nRow 2: \*dc in next 0 stitches, 2 dc in next stitch\* 6 times (12 stitches).\nRow 3: \*dc in next 1 stitches, 2 dc in next stitch\* 6 times (18 stitches).\nRow 4: \*dc in next 2 stitches, 2 dc in next stitch\* 6 times (24 stitches).\nRow 5: \*dc in next 3 stitches, 2 dc in next stitch\* 6 times (30 stitches).`
> 2. `Rnd 1: \*sc in next -1 stitches, 2 sc in next stitch\* 1 times (1 stitches).\nRnd 2: \*sc in next 0 stitches, 2 sc in next stitch\* 1 times (2 stitches).\nRnd 3: \*sc in next 1 stitches, 2 sc in next stitch\* 1 times (3 stitches).\n`
> 3. `Rnd 1: \*hdc in next -1 stitches, 2 hdc in next stitch\* 100 times (100 stitches).\nRnd 2: \*hdc in next 0 stitches, 2 hdc in next stitch\* 100 times (200 stitches).\nRnd 3: \*hdc in next 1 stitches, 2 hdc in next stitch\* 100 times (300 stitches).\nRnd 4: \*hdc in next 2 stitches, 2 hdc in next stitch\* 100 times (400 stitches).\nRnd 5: \*hdc in next 3 stitches, 2 hdc in next stitch\* 100 times (500 stitches).\nRnd 6: \*hdc in next 4 stitches, 2 hdc in next stitch\* 100 times (600 stitches).\n`
> 4. This can error, or not produce any output, or anything. R will always be positive and nonzero.
> 5. This can either error OR produce `Rnd 1: \*tc in next -1 stitches, 2 tc in next stitch\* 0 times (0 stitches).\nRnd 2: \*tc in next 0 stitches, 2 tc in next stitch\* 0 times (0 stitches).\nRnd 3: \*tc in next 1 stitches, 2 tc in next stitch\* 0 times (0 stitches).\nRnd 4: \*tc in next 2 stitches, 2 tc in next stitch\* 0 times (0 stitches).\nRnd 5: \*tc in next 3 stitches, 2 tc in next stitch\* 0 times (0 stitches).`

Suggestions for more test cases welcomed! Please let me know how to improve it. If you have an input/output that produces a pattern you like, add it to your answer and maybe I’ll crochet it when I have time.

Ungolfed solution in Python 2: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##VY7BDoIwEETvfMVmTy1UIiRcTPgFDl7VA8EqTbA07Rrt19cWMNHb7MzbyRhP46zrEPpWafMkxktnJkUMBfLMRpNYf9pfeOZaRzbqKmq/@XXUt9lCB0qD7fVdMssPGUxKyxaP8wuwSF9dUfECD5DHs8AEa/mmb7hLIThSNIzSCajhH1uTfMN9gkk9pAO2Okt97n9LeHnWmIGxceeyJgRsxHUQDX4A)

Comment: Perhaps you should be more lenient than *this format must be exact*. Would lists of the given strings be ok? Also there's a lot of `*`, `-`, and `()` dispersed through-out the output - can this be optional or removed?

Comment: A list of the strings is an acceptable output. The `* ( )` characters I don’t think should be optional, they are part of the format of crochet patterns and show repeats and stitch count.

Comment: Great! I was more concerned about the commas, the periods, the colons and the dashes - can they be optional?

Comment: This was initially posted in the sandbox but I don’t know if I can post a link to a comment on a deleted post: reference implementation in Python 2 for an older version (should still work for the current specs). [Try It Online](https://tio.run/#%23VZDBbsMgEETvfMVqewHsWI3bXCzxCxxyi@oerIQ0SC5YQKTy9e7aplFzG96MZkdMOd28a@d5UNZN98RFE6fRJo41ChYIJj58vH4KFlVMgfSedC68JW2vMBrHB6HUe8fAl9gbWWaMZkV49Hd3QfbiQXfQywjWgTM/CfSuhZhsOt9MrIH0w9loLyFDst8mAtenR1Q07OoD6CUdBvdleBB0abTOKF8hYLWs0NVeVNiBpCfBv@Zi7hbz6fhzbHNkieclXIZsZK2X@X@JaHqHDKZA37OOmWc81JdzfcBf)

Comment: I think the periods and commas are probably optional, as long as the spacing is ok. I don’t see any dashes — only the hyphens showing subtraction, which are part of computing the output. What dashes do you see, @Noodle9?

Comment: Ah, didn't realise they where negative numbers. Maybe you should have a more formal description of the output format.

Comment: Can you use preformatted text (using 4 spaced indent) to show output in the examples? The use of a proportional font in combination with `\n` doesn't make it very readable.

Comment: @Abigail: 4 space indent didn’t seem to work, so I used backticks, but fixed that.

Comment: Why does the first example start each line with 'Row', but the others start with 'Rnd'?

Comment: The first two tests were generated from the original specs allowing an input for rows/rounds, so I flipped a coin to say what it would input. The other 3 were from edge cases that popped up with my code that I wanted to clarify, plus a bigger test case, so it was using a default value.

Answer (score 1):

## perl -M5.010 -a, 124 bytes

```
say"Row $_: \\*$F[1] in next ${\($_-2)} stitches, 2 $F[1] in next stitch\\* $F[2] times (${\($_*$F[2])} stitches)."for 1..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIpKL9cQSXeSiEmRkvFLdowViEzTyEvtaJEQaU6RkMlXtdIs1ahuCSzJDkjtVhHwUgBVRFEBqgXJG4Uq1CSmZtarKAB0asFFkPSr6mnlJZfpGCop6cS//@/mUJGSrKCoYHBv/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBv91EwE)

Pretty trivial. The bulk of the program consists of the line which needs to be printed, with some variable interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 62 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
EN³*³²NÍ²N“ ÿ: \*ÿ€†‚š ÿÀŠ, 2 ÿ€†‚šïŠ\* ÿ„Æ (ÿÀŠ).“'w't:'¢ã™ì,
```

Input in the same order as the challenge description, as three loose inputs \$r,s,y\$.

I've used `Row` for the optional first word, although `Round` and `Rnd` could both also be used for the same byte-count, by replacing `'¢ã™` with `'í‰™` or `…Rnd` respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f1e/QZq1Dmw9t8jvcCyQeNcxROLzfSiFG6/D@R01rHjUseNQw6@hCoNjhhqMLdBSMFFDED68/uiBGCyTWMO9wm4IGRJmmHtAY9XL1Eiv1Q4sOL37UsujwGp3//025UpK5TAE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgZF@pw6XkX1oC5AJ5OpUJYaH/Xf0itSIj/A73Rvg9apijcHi/lUKM1uH9j5rWPGpY8Khh1tGFQLHDDUcX6CgYKaCIH15/dEGMFkisYd7hNgUNiDJNPaAx6uXqJVbqhxYdXvyoZdHhNTr/aw9ts/8fHW2qo5SSrKRjGqujAGObgdjGOkrFQLYhiG2mo5QBkjA0MABxDXSUkjOgUkAtJUAZg9hYAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
E        # Loop `N` in the range [1, (implicit) first input `r`]:
 N³*     #  Push `N` multiplied by the third input `y`
 ³       #  Push the third input `y`
 ²       #  Push the second input `s`
 NÍ      #  Push `N-2`
 ²       #  Push the second input `s` again
 N       #  Push `N`
 “ ÿ: \*ÿ€†‚š ÿÀŠ, 2 ÿ€†‚šïŠ\* ÿÀŠ (ÿ„Æ).“
         #  Push dictionary string " ÿ: \*ÿ in next ÿ switches, 2 ÿ in next switch\* ÿ times (ÿ switches).",
         #  where the `ÿ` are automatically replaced with the values on the stack
  'w't:  #  Replace all "w" with "t" ("switch" to "stitch")
  '¢ã   '#  Push dictionary string "row"
     ™   #  Titlecase it to "Row"
      ì  #  Prepend it in front of the string
       , #  And output it with trailing newline
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“ ÿ: \*ÿ€†‚š ÿÀŠ, 2 ÿ€†‚šïŠ\* ÿ„Æ (ÿÀŠ).“` is `" ÿ: \*ÿ in next ÿ switches, 2 ÿ in next switch\* ÿ times (ÿ switches)."` and `'¢ã` is `"row"`.

Comment: I'm not sure that your output is correct - it says `(Ny times)` instead of `y times (Ny stitches)`.

Comment: And there should be ``\``s before the `*`s... (fortunately I spotted that error in my code before the grace period expired!)

Comment: ... except I forgot to update my byte count, oops...

Comment: @Neil Thanks for noticing. Should be fixed now. EDIT: After I've fixed the slashes. EDIT2: Done

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 132 bytes

```
^\d+
*
Lv^$`(_+) (.+) (.+)
Row $.1: \$*$2 in next $1 stitches, 2 $2 in next stitch\$* $3 times ($.($3*$1) stitches).
__(_*)
$.1
_
-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy9CsIwFIX3@xRnuEKSakgs7eALuDg5l6aSBprBCiaobx8DirgcON/5uYcc14stG3GcyjjMDSk6PUaehGskhP4KnW9PsLYHDKx4j7hiDa8Mtkg5Zr@EtMUef8kH1za4RY7XkCBYC24VW/kbSU3OCack1XNytLOldJg9emqRPCz1WKq1xpCBXyrokD3MGw) Takes input in the order `r`, `s`, `y`. Explanation:

```
^\d+
*
```

Convert `r` to unary.

```
Lv^$`(_+) (.+) (.+)
```

Count down from `r` to `1`, then reverse the results, and substitute in the output pattern:

```
Row $.1: \$*$2 in next $1 stitches, 2 $2 in next stitch\$* $3 times ($.($3*$1) stitches).
```

`$.1` is the row, `$*` is a literal `*`, `$2` is `s`, `$1` is the row in unary, `$3` is `y`, and `$.($3*$1)` is the product of the row with `y` (in decimal).

```
__(_*)
$.1
```

Subtract 2 from the row for the final substitution.

```
_
-1
```

Fix up the first row.